# Simple form does not get $_POST value and cannot submit

Tags: php, html, forms, post

Somehow this takes me a day and still does not solve, I have other forms that works properly. But this one looks perfect but it simply refresh the page after I submit the form.

```
 <form action="" enctype='multipart/form-data' name= 'myForm' id="myForm" method='post'>


<label>
<span>Product Name</span><input id="product_name" value='<?php echo $product_name;?>'     type="text" name="product_name"  disabled >
</label>

<label>
<span>Retail Price</span> <input name='retail_price' value="<?php echo $retail_price;?>"  type='text' id='retail_price' size='10' disabled >
</label>

<label>
<span>Discount (%)</span> <input name='discount' value="<?php echo $discount;?>" type='text' id='discount' size='10'disabled  >
</label>
<label>
<span>Details</span><textarea id="details" class="product_details" placeholder="For any other reasons, please provide details here" name="details"></textarea>
</label>

<label>
<span>Reason to Report</span>
<select name='reason' id='reason' class="required">
<option value = '' > </option>
<option value = 'price10' > Product price is higher than $9.9</option>
<option value = 'shelf' > Product is off the shelf</option>
<option value = 'no_fs' > Product does not have free-shipping</option>
<option value = 'reject' > Seller does not deliver products</option>
<option value = 'price_not_match' > Product Price does not match on Upto9 </option>
<option value = 'category' > Product is in wrong category </option>
<option value = 'other' > Other reasons</option>
</label>

<label>
<input name='submit' type='submit' id='button' class="button" value="Submit Report"/>
</label>

</form>
```

THen This is my php code :

```
echo 'before';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
echo 'after';
var_dump($_POST); 
$con= mysqli_connect("xxxxx.com"," admin","xxxxx","xxxxx") or die(mysqli_error($con));
$details=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['details']);
$reason=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['reason']);
$ip = preg_replace('#[^0-9.]#', '', getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));
$sql="INSERT INTO reports (pid,product_name,listing_price,links,discount,retail_price,details,stock_level,reason,report_time,reporter,reporter,ip) VALUES 
                    ('$pid','$product_name','$listing_price','$links','$discount','$retail_price','$details','$stock_level','$reason',now(),'$log_username','$ip')";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);                      
mysqli_insert_id($con); 
mysqli_close($con);
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
echo "successful!";}
```

The output is: befre
after I added the sql code var_dump($_POST) gives me nothing, so probably the sql code is wrong...

Comment: Are you working with http://stackoverflow.com/users/3653498/cfaulk? He has the same `sumbit` typo in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25374053/post-form-to-mysqli-using-php

Comment: You have a typo: `$_POST['sumbit']` should be `$_POST['submit']`

Comment: If that's not the whole problem, you ned to post more code.

Comment: i have made the edition, please kindly take a look

Comment: if you put `echo "before";` before that, and `echo "after";` after it, do you see those things?

Comment: ya i see them on the top of my page for echo 'before', but echo 'after' is never seen after form submission

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST)` show?

Comment: You're missing `</select>` at the end of your `<select>`, but I don't think that would cause this problem.

Comment: it gives me array(0) { } and I added / to my select, and still no luck

Comment: after i play around, I get this : afterarray(4) { ["reason"]=> string(5) "shelf" ["subject"]=> string(0) "" ["details"]=> string(19) "product is not good" ["submit"]=> string(13) "Submit Report" }

Comment: take a look in the DOM inspector, make sure all the input fields are actually inside the `<form>` element. Maybe you have another typo that's messing this up.

Comment: Does your `if` work then? What do you mean by play around?

Comment: playing around means getting rid of the sql code and putting it back..

Comment: So you probably had a typo somewhere that was breaking things. But it wasn't in the code you posted, so we can't tell what you did wrong.

Comment: yeah, I will have to figure those out myself, but thanks for your time and help. I really appreciate it!

Comment: why does your form have no action? Why is it `action=""` instead of `action="."` or `action="myfile.php"`?